# Не могу установить и настроить SASS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, npm, sass

Я не знаю ничего про Node.js но хотел установить SASS.

вот фото. Должно было компилировать SASS на style.min.css. Пробовал и через терминал Гит [image: Должно было компилировать SASS на style.min.css]

Comment: `var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));` пробуйте так, как вам подсказывает консоль

Comment: Ваш вопрос никак не связан с Node - Вам требуется настроить сборку через gulp.
Скорее всего Вы взяли что то готовое. Текущая версия gulp -4, возможно Ваш пример из 3 версии gulp - написание конфигурациооного файла отличается у 3 и 4 версии. Уроки на русском есть , например на youtube